# ORMLite, JSON and Foreign object

Tags: json, gson, ormlite

Lets say I have this simple ORMLite (consider annotations added, this is just pseudocode) datamodel in an Android App:

```
A
{
   String id;
}

B
{
   String id;

   A A_id;
}
```

Taking into account that I will receive objects from a PostgreSQL external database like this where A_id will be a String (the remote database stores references as foreign keys), how would I proceed in order to converto from JSON to ORMLite?. At this moment, we are doing it like this (using GSON):

```
B
{
    String id;

    String A_id;
}
```

But this implies we have to make multiple queries when navigating from B to referenced B and this is not the best way to make use of any ORM.

The question is if ORMLite implements a way to do this because we have not been able to find any docs about it (there is a lot regarding collections, but nothing on a simple reference).

Thanks in advance,

Jose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but you could use [JSON ODM](https://github.com/konsultaner/jsonOdm) instead that supports joining.

I wrote that library because I missed joining in a lot of other libraries. Even mongodb itself does not support joining. It's still in development but has 100% code-coverage. So all supported methods should be considered stable as far as no issue is raised. I use it in a lot of my projects.

If you like it please give it a star.